# Tailwind + WebStorm: "unknown CSS at rule"

Tags: webstorm, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Tailwind with my WebStorm IDE, however, I get this error:

> Unknown CSS at rule

whenever I use `@apply` or `@tailwind`

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to disable at-rules errors in your configuration IDE. You can choose this syntax. Hope this will help :)

```css
// noinspection CssInvalidAtRule
@tailwind base;
// noinspection CssInvalidAtRule
@tailwind components;
// noinspection CssInvalidAtRule
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 7):

Tailwind  is not currently supported, please follow [WEB-42792](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42792) and linked tickets for updates.

Disabling **Unknown CSS at-rule** inspection in **Preferences | Editor | Inspections | CSS | Invalid elements** is the only way to avoid *Unknown CSS At Rule* error; note that some Tailwind rules can cause syntax errors that come from low level checking and can't be disabled (like *Unexpected token*, etc.). In such cases,  I can only suggest turning the syntax highlighting off for such files to avoid errors: open your file in editor, click the *Hector* icon in the lower right corner and then move the slider to change the **Highlighting level** to *None*, then re-open the project. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#change-highlighting-level-for-file.

**Update**: Tailwind is officially supported starting from version 2020.3.

Comment: As of IntelliJ 2020.3 there's now official Tailwind support via a plugin, hooray!

Answer (score 6):

IMHO disabling the inspection is the wrong way to go since the point of this inspection is to warn whether the rule is correct or not, and here the problem is merely that the IDE doesn't know of it :)

To fix that you can add the Tailwind plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15321-tailwind-css).
It will make the IDE aware of the new rules, and add a lot of new features like class autocompletion :)

Comment: But why do that if disabling a couple features also solves the problem, as proposed in the two top answers?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I had to disable the inspection `Unknown CSS at-rule - This inspection detects unknown CSS at-rules.` from my `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Inspections` under the `CSS` -> `Invalid elements` category

Answer (score 3):

Install tailwind css plugin to support tailwind. See link below
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tailwind-css.html

Comment: This is an official JetBrains plugin, and as of 2024, this is better than disabling the inspection.